# Conflict between fmtcount and longtable packages?

Tags: longtable, fmtcount

I have quite happily been using the two together for years, with `fmtcount` included in a `\RequirePackage` in my class definition, and `longtable` included as a `\usepackage` in the document files themselves.

But since I use `longtable` quite a lot, I decided to move it into my class definition file.  The result was an error.  Here is a very basic stripped-down example.  The class definition file is:

```
\ProvidesClass{TableExample}

\RequirePackage{fmtcount}
\RequirePackage{longtable}

\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}
```

Then a document that uses it is:

```
\documentclass{TableExample}

\begin{document}
Useless text.
\end{document}
```

This produces the following error when complied with pdflatex:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@table already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.463 \newcounter{table}
```

I was surprised, because I've been using these together for years, just using `fmtcount` in the class definition file, and `longtable` in the document itself.  So I figured maybe there is some sort of scope issue - the redefinition is perhaps allowable if it does not occur at the same stage of processing, maybe?  (So, before processing the class definition file, versus after?)  But after a little experimentation, I found this file compiles with no difficulty at all.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
Useless text.
\end{document}
```

I did some searching, and found some links stating that the only real difference between `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage` is that `\RequirePackage` can be issued before the `\documentclass` command, which isn't the case here.  So I'm mystified as to why the two packages coexist when included in two successive `\usepackage` commands, but conflict when included in two successive `\RequirePackage` commands.

For what it's worth, I never use the two packages in the same part of the document (for example, I never use an `fmtcount` capability inside a `longtable`), but I imagine there might be trouble if I were to do that.  Haven't tried it yet.

One remedy is just to leave things as they are, since they don't seem to be causing problems, and just continue to include `longtable` in my document files, rather than in the class definition.  I'm just wondering why I get this odd behaviour.

Comment: You can reproduce this with `\RequirePackage{longtable}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Useless text.
\end{document}`. As far as I can see `fmtcount` has nothing to do with this. If you make sure to load the `longtable` package *after* the `article` class in `TableExample.cls`, the problem is gone.

Comment: You are correct, I think I made a mistake in my debugging procedure that caused me to think that fmtcount came into play.  But I just removed it, and the error occurs exactly as is.

Following your suggestion, moving the \RequirePackage{longtable} to after loading the class solves the problem - many thanks!

Comment: Important moral of the story: **it's not my fault** :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - That's also the gist of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431996/5001). :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @moewe has pointed out in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431995/5001), the issue you're experiencing is not related to the `fmtcount` package. Instead, it is related solely to the fact that the `longtable` package is being loaded *before* rather than after the `article` document class file is loaded. The file `longtable.sty` contains the following code chunk:

```
\ifx\c@table\undefined
  \newcounter{table}
  \def\fnum@table{\tablename~\thetable}
\fi
```

I.e., a test is performed to see if a counter variable named `table` exists; if it does not, this counter is created via a `\newcounter` statement. (The code also creates a macro called `\fnum@table`, but that's not relevant here.) One can only surmise that the [author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) of the `longtable` package chose to insert this chunk out of an overabundance of caution, to guard against a situation in which an unfortunate user is employing some nasty and brutish document class which, for unknowable reasons, does not provide a counter named `table`. (I suppose this includes the `minimal` document class, which -- as its name implies -- should never be used for the creation of "real" documents. For sure, I can't foresee why anyone would wish to create a `longtable` while using the `minimal` document class.)

As you can probably guess by now, the `article` document class *does* define a counter named `table`, via (how else?) a

```
\newcounter{table}
```

statement. Note that no precautions are taken in `article.cls` to check if a counter variable named `table` is already defined. In consequence, the LaTeX kernel spits out an error message and self-terminates. I think it's fair to say that the authors of the `article` document class (and of the other "standard" LaTeX document classes, such as `report` and `book`) simply did not anticipate the contingency of a package that defines the `table` counter being loaded *before* the document class is loaded.

You also stated that

> I did some searching, and found some links stating that the only real difference between `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage` is that `\RequirePackage` can be issued before the `\documentclass` command...

This statement is partially correct as it relies on the weasel-verb "can be issued". However, it wouldn't be correct to infer that there are no consequences to loading a given package before or after the document class file. Otherwise, why even make a distinction between `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage` -- and why not load all packages *before* loading the document class? As you've discovered the hard way, some "real differences" do exist...

---

What's the moral of this story? In your own document class, which indirectly loads the `article` document class, you should make a habit of loading all packages *after* the following code chunk:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}
```

*unless* you have a very good reason for loading the package(s) before loading the `article` document class. What might be such a "very good reason"? As [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) has pointed out in a comment, "Packages should be loaded before `\LoadClass` or `\LoadPackage` *only if necessary for setting up the code related to class or package options*." [emphasis added] To the best of my knowledge, there are very few such packages. One such package was [fixltx2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e), which contained various fixes to the LaTeX kernel that were discovered between 1994 and 2015. If your LaTeX kernel is more recent than 2015/11/30, it's not necessary (or even advisable!) to load this package.

Comment: Packages should be loaded before `\LoadClass` or `\LoadPackage` only if necessary for setting up the code related to class or package options.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for this. I'll edit my posting to include this message.

Comment: The `letter` class (which is one of the base classes) doesn't define `table`, so it's useful if you need a table in a letter (for example, if it's an invoice). Since `longtable` is quite old, there may not have been any other letter-like classes around when it was written.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot - Thanks for this. I must confess to never having used the `letter` document class, ever, for any of my own work; I was quite unaware until just now of the fact that it doesn't define a counter variable named `table` either. Good thing I didn't write that `letter` was among the "standard" LaTeX document classes. :-) [I'll let others fight over what is "standard"...]

Comment: @Mico I first used it back in the day when it was `\documentstyle{letter}` ;-) then when LaTeX2e appeared I made a custom class based on `letter.cls` and still use it. There's no real need for floats in a letter and `tabular` has always been sufficient for my letter-writing needs.

Answer (score 6):

The same problem can be reproduced with

```
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Useless text.
\end{document}
```

`longtable.sty` defines the counter `table` if it is not defined. But then the `article` class tries to define the `table` counter as well.

The solution is to load `longtable` after the (real) document class. So your `.cls` could look like

```
\ProvidesClass{TableExample}

\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{fmtcount}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have moved all my \RequirePackage statements to after the article class is loaded.  All except ifthen, since I use it to process my class options.